# Creating and pushing new object into react state array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working on a react form with multiple form elements, and an option to repeat the whole form. Basically a add more button which adds a new form block.

To keep track of multiple forms, I created a formModel object in a different file and imported this to my react from component.

```
var formModel = {
    counter : 0,
    formElements : {
        text1 : '',
        text2 : '',
        select1: '',
        radio: ''
    }
};

export default formModel;
```

In my component which handles the form I import it and initialize the state with 1 object of this formModel, as I need to show a minimum of one form block. I have a Add mode/Remove option where I add/remove a form block.

```
class FormComponent extends React.Component {

    constructor(){
      super()
      this.state = {
        formList: [formModel]   
      };
    }

    addAnother(){
        let nextFormList = this.state.formList;
        nextFormList.push(formModel);
        this.setState({
            formList: nextFormList
        });
    }


    render() {
      return (
        //I map over the formList and send my form state as props into a formElement component
      );
    }
  }
```

My issue, is when I try to add a new object of formModel in the addAnother method into my formList array in state, it keeps adding the same initial copy of formModel.

I'm unable to create a new copy of the formModel object and keep pushing the same copy.

I'm guessing a basic JS concept of creating objects which I'm unable to implement.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I correctly clone a JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728360/how-do-i-correctly-clone-a-javascript-object)

Comment: Your guess is correct.

Comment: Thank you. Is there any other way to approach this without the need to make a copy of the object and insert it into the array in the state?

Comment: @vivekh Why don't you want to do this? It is basically a one-liner.

Answer (score 4):

Two things you should avoid when using state:

1. **[Do not mutate objects in the current state](https://reactjs.org/docs/optimizing-performance.html#the-power-of-not-mutating-data)**. Always create new objects to update the state. You can use the spread operator for that.
2. **[Calls to `setState` are asynchronous - don’t rely on `this.state` to reflect the new value immediately after calling `setState`](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-state.html#why-is-setstate-giving-me-the-wrong-value)**. Use the callback version of `setState()` instead. React batches updates and when the update happens `this.state` does not contain the data from previously scheduled updates and may override them.

Example:

```
addAnother(){
    this.setState(oldState => ({
        formList: [...oldState.formList, formModel]
    }));
}
```